# Oracle convert rows into dynamic columns based on one column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

**What I have**

An Oracle table with below data

```
COL1  COL2
----  ----
1001  110
1001  111
1001  112
2001  210
2001  211
```

**What I want is**

```
1001  110  111  112
2001  210  210
```

Basically I want all the values in COL2 which match to COL1 on the same line.

How can I achieve this in Oracle?
Please note the number of columns should grow based on available matching rows.
If that is not possible, then we can consider max 5 values.

Comment: To be clear, you want **separate columns** for each occurrence of COL2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is to put them in one column using `list_agg()`:

```
select col1, listagg(col2, ' ') within group (order by col2) as col2s
from t
group by col1;
```

For separate columns, I would recommend `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select col1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then col2 end) as col2_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then col2 end) as col2_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then col2 end) as col2_3
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by col1;
```